# USB3.0 Differential Pair Eye Diagram - Transmitter Issues

Tags: usb, signal-integrity, high-speed, eye-diagram

Used the SI Power Aware analysis on the DP/DM signals for this simulation:

[image]

I'm having more issues on my Tx rather than the Rx. I do understand the Rx eye diagram but I'm struggling with the wild results I got for the TX. Anyone who can help me interpret?

The Tx results are ok using line models, it's only when I use the EM model extracted from the layout that I'm getting this result.

Edit:

Added the ChannelSim Schematic:

[image]

Comment: Do you only have issue with it in simulation or even it measures like that? My main guess is that you have more reflection on your TX line then on your RX. Your RX seems a bit too clean. Can you share your schematics for the simulation?

Comment: I was also very suspicious of that, it's too clean. Added the ChannelSim schematic @Julien

Comment: I can't tell what that box is between the transmitter and the receiver.  Is it a passive coupler of some sort?  But it's possible that the Rx looks clean because any reflections from the Rx end are going to show up on the Tx side of things, not at the receiver.

Comment: It's an extra SnP port (currently deactivated) @SteveSh

Comment: And where is your pre-emphasis/de-emphasis on Tx end? Do you have a realistic channel model, per USB specifications? Honestly, I never have seen this shape of signals in reality...